# JS: can I pass dictionary to xhr.send()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to pass `dictionary` to `xhr.send()` function like this:

```
xhr.send( {
  'first_key': 'value',
  'second_key': 'value',
  ...
} );
```

Or like this:

```
xhr.send('{"hello":"world"}')
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `JSON.stringify` and `setRequestHeader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

The argument to `send()` can be:

> - A Document, in which case it is serialized before being sent.
> - A BodyInit, which as per the Fetch spec can be a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, ReadableStream, or USVString object.

You cannot pass a plain object, but you can pass a string.

Make sure you use `setRequestHeader` to specify that your content-type if application/json is you are posting a string of JSON.

Comment: Doesn't work: I set up header and sent `JSON.stringify(dict)`, on my server I have only empty dict.

Comment: @0x3E7 — Then, assuming you aren't running into a preflight request issue which would be reported on the Console of the browser's Developer Tools … you are probably doing something wrong on the server as you try to read the request.

Comment: `print( request.POST )` outputs `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: I don't know my way around whatever framework you are using.

Comment: I've already find what was wrong: JSON string was in `request.body`.